# How to edit a value in an ownedField?

Tags: youtrack

I created a custom value for "Subsystem" field in YouTrack, but I forgot to set its color. Now I want to set its color, but I can't find how could I do that. There is no button to edit a value or to remove a value from the field:

[image]

I just want to give the "Graphics" value a different color. I have all the privileges on YouTrack to edit the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a link to the right from the owner, but it's invisible due to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-33576 (icons are missing in Chrome 49+). You can either do some pixelhunting to find the control or user another browser.

Comment: Haha, great time for me to start using YouTrack : )